# Connecting Oracle to Play Framework 2.1.5

Tags: oracle, jdbc, playframework, database-connection

I am still new in the Play! Framework universe. I'd like to ask you folks a question. I am trying to connect Oracle to my application. Thus, I added this in the application.conf file:

```
  db.default.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
  db.default.url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/test"
  db.default.user=scott
  db.default.password="tiger"
```

And of course added the dependencies. But it's still not working and it throws me a beautiful exception:

> "Configuration error : Cannot connect to database [default]"

Am I wrong in something? Please I really need help.

Thanks.

###########################

@Frank Schmitt : nope I didn't tried this.
@wwkudu : by running my application, I get this :

```
[error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to obtain initial connection Sle
eping for 0ms and trying again. Attempts left: 0. Exception: null
[error] application -

! @6h70iggbo - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [
default]]
        at play.api.Configuration$.play$api$Configuration$$configError(Configura
tion.scala:81) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.5]
        at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:559) ~[play_2.
10.jar:2.1.5]
        at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:251) ~[pla
y-jdbc_2.10.jar:2.1.5]
        at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:242) ~[pla
y-jdbc_2.10.jar:2.1.5]
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike
.scala:244) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike
.scala:244) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Exception d'E/S: Got minus one from a read cal
l
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java
:112) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.2.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.1.0"]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java
:146) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.2.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.1.0"]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java
:255) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.2.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.1.0"]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:387) ~[ojdb
c14-10.2.0.2.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.1.0"]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:
414) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.2.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.1.0"]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165) ~[ojd
bc14-10.2.0.2.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.1.0"]
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Play!, but should'nt you put the username (scott) in quotes, as well?

Comment: Nope I don't think so. As I followed in the documentation on the internet, it is the right syntax. But I may be wrong... I tried all the issues...

Comment: Can you connect to the database using other clients (e.g. sqlplus)?

Comment: if you look in the stack trace on the console where you enter `play run`, is there an additional clue. for example i can see `Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user 'jtadmn'@'localhost' to database 'ju...` here on my non-oracle-db setup, several lines down into the trace.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the Database named test exists

Comment: I created another database on purpose just to test it, named it play... but still not working